# Track and apply fixed positioning in frame for subject

Tags: davinci-resolve, blackmagic

I used tripod to film a subject which is speaking and their head is moving around ever so slightly.
I want to to position the subject based on their eyes so that their eyes do not move at all. I am projecting this video on a Styrofoam head and it is critical the the eye position remain fixed.
I've tried stabilizer, but it still produces a moving subject. I've attempted to use transform and keyframes, but it does not look that good.

Is there a better way to stabilize a subject at a fixed position using a tracker in Davinci Resolve?